# How can I open/show the default content-help-dialog with quickly?

Tags: application-development, quickly, pygtk

If I create a Quickly-Project there is a default Menubar which shows the Help-Dialog(Contents - "index.page" from help/C - Folder). How can I manually show the Content-Help Dialog? There is no code in the created default-project.
Background: I have more than one dialogs in my app. I want to show/reach the content-dialog in every dialog of my app and also not only from the Menubar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution on: [Gnome documentation](https://live.gnome.org/DocumentationProject/Tasks/DesktopHelp) and [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html).
With the python command,

```
import commands
...
commands.getstatusoutput(yelp path/to/index.page)
```

I am able show the index.page file in my app.